# Navigator.sendBeacon() to pass header information

Tags: javascript, w3c

I am using [navigator](https://www.w3.org/TR/beacon/) for communicating with the server , but problem is that we need to pass some header information as there is filter which recognise the request is from the valid source.

Can anybody help on this?

Thanks.

Comment: @scotty-h any update on this? are we allowed to set custom headers especially "Auth" or "Authorization" to allow requests to be white-listed for REST APIs? I think cors-safelist warning is removed by Chrome and Firefox as of mid 2021. We aim to use **sendBeacon()** with custom Auth headers a lot in [timeonsite tracker](https://saleemkce.github.io/timeonsite) for analytics, this is crucial metric.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

See the `Navigator.sendBeacon` [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) for further information.

Create a blob to provide headers. Here is an example:

```
window.onunload = () => {
  const body = {
    id,
    email,
  };
  const headers = {
    type: 'application/json',
  };
  const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(body)], headers);
  navigator.sendBeacon('url', blob);
};
```

`navigator.sendBeacon` will send a POST request with the Content-Type request header set to whatever is in `headers.type`. This seems to be the only header you can set in a beacon though, per [W3C](https://w3c.github.io/beacon/):

> The sendBeacon method does not provide ability to customize the request method, provide custom request headers, or change other processing properties of the request and response. Applications that require non-default settings for such requests should use the [FETCH] API with keepalive flag set to true.

I was able to observe some of how this worked through this [Chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=466038).

Comment: Yes  you are completely correct as this is an experimental approach as per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) and only available in latest browser such as chrome v39.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but keepalive for fetch isn't even implemented in Chrome yet . https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/loading-dev/_F6oicQ3_F4

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not allowed anymore and will throw an error due to security reasons as of Chrome 59. See: https://crbug.com/720283

Comment: @Scotty This doesn't works with Authorization headers

Comment: As a follow-up to @MarcelPanse, it works again since Chrome 81. See: https://crbug.com/724929

Comment: Should use `visibilitychange`

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function logData() {
  if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
    navigator.sendBeacon("/log", analyticsData);
  }
});
Cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Answer (score 17):

I want to call an api when someone close the tab, so I tried to use `navigator.sendBeacon()` but the problem is we need to pass the `Authorization` token into it and `sendBeacon` does not provide that, so I found other solution that is more effective and very easy to implement.

The solution is a native `fetch` API with a `keepalive` flag in `pagehide` event.

**Code**

```
window.addEventListener('pagehide', () => {
  fetch(`<URL>`, {
    keepalive: true,
    method: '<METHOD>',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      // any header you can pass here
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ data: 'any data' }),
  });
});
```

#### FAQs / TL;DR Version

1. **Why should we need to use the keepalive flag?**

   - The `keepalive` option can be used to allow the request to outlive the page. `Fetch` with the keepalive flag is a replacement for the `Navigator.sendBeacon()` API.
   - Learn more about it, please visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#parameters
2. **What is PageLifecycle API**

   [image]

   - Learn more about it, please visit https://developer.chrome.com/blog/page-lifecycle-api/
3. **From the Page Lifecycle image, shouldn't `unload` be considered as the best choice?**

   - `unload` is the best event for this case but `unload` is not firing in some cases on `mobile` and it also does not support the `bfcache` functionality.
   - I also notice that when I am using `unload` then I am not getting proper output in the server log. why? IDK, if you know about it then comments are welcome.
   - Nowadays, It's also not recommended by the developers.
   - Learn more about why unload is not recommended: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event#usage_notes
   - Learn more about `pagehide`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event

Comment: This answer just made my day! You've saved me so much time and frustration. Thanks

Comment: Should use `visibilitychange`

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function logData() {
  if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
    navigator.sendBeacon("/log", analyticsData);
  }
});
Cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Comment: If you want to use extra headers then it is not useful

Answer (score 7):

As written in the [Processing Model of sendBeacon](https://w3c.github.io/beacon/#sec-processing-model) :

> Extract object's byte stream (transmittedData) and content type (contentType).

How extraction is performed is [described here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-bodyinit-extract)

*What I've gathered* is that the content type of the transmitted data is extracted, and it is set as the Content-Type of the HTTP request.

1) If a Blob object is sent, the Content-Type becomes the Blob's type.

2) If a FormData object is sent, the Content-Type becomes multipart/form-data

3) If a URLSearchParams object is sent, the Content-Type becomes application/x-www-form-urlencoded

4) If a normal string is sent, the Content-Type becomes text/plain

Javascript code to implement different objects [can be found here](http://usefulangle.com/post/63/javascript-navigator-sendbeacon-set-form-http-header)

Comment: 3) Does not work in Chrome see:https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=747787  the Content-Type is still `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Chrome and you're trying to set the content-type header, you'll probably have some issues due to security restrictions:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'sendBeacon' on 'Navigator': sendBeacon() with a Blob whose type is not any of the CORS-safelisted values for the Content-Type request header is disabled temporarily. See http://crbug.com/490015 for details.
```

See [sendBeacon API not working temporarily due to security issue, any workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274021/sendbeacon-api-not-working-temporarily-due-to-security-issue-any-workaround)

Answer (score 2):

Because the method sendBeacon(..) does not allow headers manipulation, I added them into the form as normal fields:

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('authorization', myAuthService.getCachedToken());
    navigator.sendBeacon(myURL, formData);
```

Then on the host side I added a simple Middleware class (.Net) which catches POST requests without headers and copies them from the body:

```
    public class AuthMiddleware
    {
        ...
        ...
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (authHeader == null && context.Request.Method=="POST")
            {
                context.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Bearer {0}",
                    context.Request.Form["authorization"].ToString());
            }

            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to add the middleware before the other such

Answer (score 1):

After searching for an answer for this question I found out that for passing header with navigator we need to pass a blob object.

**For example**

```
var headers = {type: 'application/json'};
var blob = new Blob(request, headers);
navigator.sendBeacon('url/to/send', blob);
```

Comment: Did you mean to capitalize `new blob` so that it would be `new Blob`?

Comment: Also what is `request`? Can you cite any of your sources?

Comment: the request i am talking about is a list of ticket data that needs to be send while the browser closes along with a security header so that server can recognise the it as a authorise request.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer as I'm not allowed to post a comment under the answer:

For Chrome, issue with navigator.sendBeacon sending Blob for with non CORS-safelisted types was fixed in Chrome version 81 so this should be safe to use now.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=724929

For IE, an alternative in unload event is to use synchronous ajax request, as IE doesn't support sendBeacon but supports synchronous ajax call in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send data with JSON after Chrome 39, has been disabled due to a security concern.

You can try to send data with plain text. But don't forget the parseing text from the backend.