# Call a POST request for logging from window unload

Tags: javascript, window, onbeforeunload, navigator, onunload

I have been struggling to write code that will make a POST request reliably on close of the tab window. [`Navigator.sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) seems to be exactly what I need (I only require this to work for Google Chrome).

```
$(global).bind('unload', function () {
  let body = {
    UserEmail: appState.user.email,
    Job: {
      Id: appState.jobId
    },
    Timestamp: '/Date(' + new Date().getTime() + ')/',
    EventOrigin: 'PdfReviewClient',
    Event: 'JobClosed'
  };
  let headers = {
    Authorization: `JWT ${authenticationState.token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf8'
  };
  let blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(body)], headers);
  navigator.sendBeacon(configuration.rootApiUrl + 'jobevents', blob);
});
```

My beacon includes custom headers, that's why I create a Blob.

However, this request does not seem to be happening. This is especially hard to debug since the window closes. So the question is, why is my beacon not sending?

Comment: I'm assuming you verified that the request happens when *not* done on browser close?

Comment: @Jorg Yes, I have. Good thought, thanks for checking, but that's not the problem in this case.

Comment: And the unload itself triggers, too? You might be able to test it with an `alert` to see if it blocks the window from closing

Comment: @Jorg I wasn't able to test with an `alert` (may not be allowed, as it's [not allowed in onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) (see Notes section)), but I can debug through the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was the only header you can set with `navigator.sendBeacon` is Content-Type, and you set that by setting `type` in the Blob options. The server route had to be modified to accommodate the request without an Authorization header (I passed it as a URL parameter instead - weird for a POST request, but seemingly the only way to do that with a beacon). Here's how it looked in the end:

```
$(global).bind('unload', function () {
  if(appState.jobId == null) return;

  let headers = {
    type: 'application/json'
  };

  let jobEventLoggingBody = {
    UserEmail: appState.user.email,
    Job: {
      Id: appState.jobId
    },
    Timestamp: '/Date(' + new Date().getTime() + ')/',
    EventOrigin: 'PdfReviewClient',
    Event: 'JobClosed'
  };
  let jobEventLoggingUrl = `${configuration.rootApiUrl}jobevents?jwt=${authenticationState.token}`;
  let jobEventLoggingBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(jobEventLoggingBody)], headers);
  navigator.sendBeacon(jobEventLoggingUrl, jobEventLoggingBlob);
});
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523469/navigator-sendbeacon-to-pass-header-information/41729668#41729668) which specifically addresses sending headers in beacons.

Comment: I ran into the same issue - I just had to send the data as a query string. Thanks for the q + a. Anyone know why this is (since usually query string is for GET, and since sendBeacon is a POST request, I expected the values I send to be in the body).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could help you. You could use this to debug.

```
function logData() {
  var newWindow = window.open();
  newWindow.document.write("ohai");
}

window.addEventListener("unload", logData, false);
```