# API call when tab closing angular 5

Tags: angular5

I'm working on angular 5 project. So that I want to call API when closing tab. How can use "beforeunload" or any Technic to this.

Comment: what you mean by tab? is it a component?

Comment: No. tab means browser window tab.

Comment: I need to call http request  "https://*********.com/sessionStatus"  when closing browser tab

Comment: this one is similar to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642589/how-can-we-detect-when-user-closes-browser/37642657

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999842/angular-2-execute-code-when-closing-window/39005933

Comment: same as my question. But this solution is not work for when tab closing. Can't display any alert also when tab closing. It works only when refreshing.

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake. Your answer is worked for me. Thank You.

Comment: Is there any method to find $event is refresh event of tab close event

Answer (score 0):

'beforeunload' would be trigger when refreshing pages, closing tab, or closing the browser.

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeUnload(e: Event) {
      e.returnValue = false;
  }
```

You can set 'e.returnValue = false;' or 'return false;' to show a confirm dialogue from browser. But You can not show the customized message by return string since April 2016.
refer to https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/chrome-51-deprecations?hl=en#remove_custom_messages_in_onbeforeunload_dialogs

You can set 'navigator.sendBeacon()' in beforeunload event to send a POST API. 
However 'navigator.sendBeacon()' can only POST API, and it can't set customized header like token. (refer to [Navigator.sendBeacon() to pass header information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523469/navigator-sendbeacon-to-pass-header-information))

Some document recommend using fetch with attribute 'keepalive':

```
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    fetch(url, {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'authorization': token
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        credentials: 'include',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        keepalive: true,
      })
```

But keepalive is not working now in chrome M78, which is reported but not fixed.(refer to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=835821)